# Bootstrap 4 flexible layout: IE8 and IE9 support

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, flexbox, fallback, bootstrap-4

I would really love to use Bootstrap 4 and its flexible grid system, but at the same time I need to support IE8 and IE9, so I am searching for ways how to make this work.

I have tried the [flexibility.js](https://github.com/10up/flexibility), but for some reason, it's not working for me at all (see https://github.com/10up/flexibility/issues/51).

I was also thinking of using some condition that would generate a normal Bootstrap 4 grid without a flex option, but not sure what would be the best approach.

**I would like to discuss about the best possibilities how to provide flex Bootstrap 4 for IE8 and 9.**

Comment: I hate to say it, but you won't find much support for IE8 with modern frameworks. Microsoft doesn't even support it anymore...

Comment: Let's not give up. Let's find out how. Some products' websites need to support IE 8 and 9, but want to use modern technologies at the same time. :)

Comment: I tried flexibility too, but it's not working for me either.

Comment: But I don't understand why. I did everything according to the tutorial, but it seems like the script did not activated or what.

Comment: @VeryCurious looks like the issue is closed in the GitHub repo(https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility/issues/51). Could you please check & confirm if your issue is solved.? I am going to start a new project for which we are considering bootstrap 4 potentially. But the users still use older versions of IE at least 8+ your feedback is appreciated.